# Report depend on SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, sharepoint-2010, report

I have simple list in SharePoint just contain Task name,From,to and percent value

where I could assign some task to other one and each week he should update the percent of complete value.

The task maybe take 5-6 weeks So I need a report to know in current week for example which user update his task and the old value and the new value he change.

So I need away to have such report where I could set from date to date and it report which task is changed by who and the changed value.

I'm using normal list in SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve it this way: 
1. Create another column in your list (I call it OriginalList) called PreviousPercentValue and set its default value to [Percent Value]
2. Create another list (for example Reports) with columns: [Previous Percent Value], [Current Percent Value]
3. In Reports, add two additional columns to the default view: Created, Created By 
4. Create a workflow in SharePoint Designer on OriginalList, activated on modification, that will check if PreviousPrecentValue is different than [Percent Value] and if yes, then:
a) Create a new item in Reports with values: Reports.[Previous Percent Value]=OriginalList.PreviousPercentValue, Reports.[Current Percent Value] = OriginalList.[Percent Value].
[Created] and [Created By] will be set automatically for you. I am not sure if [Created By] will be set properly, if not then create another column in Reports called User and in the workflow, set its value to OriginalList.[Modified By] 
b) Set OriginalList.PreviousPercentValue to OriginalList.[Percent Value]

This way, every record in your new list Reports will have data you need: who, when, old + new percent values. You can add views on Reports to customize data you want to see.